# Multiple Screen Issue

Tags: android

I have my application running in Android Tab. But when I am delpoying in Nexus One or some other smaller device, my UI getting out of bound. 
I have gone through documentaion I have found I have to use 
I applied in my manifest file But not getting output.
Can anyone help me here.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create multiple layouts for different screens. Just create folders named as layout-small, layout-large etc, Android OS will handle it according to the device. For more information read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).