# Issue with Multiple Screens in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have my application developed for Samasung TAB exclusively. But when I am deploying to mobile devices such as NexusOne, the UI is going off the screen. 
I read documentation, I found I need to add  inside my manifest file.        I did but it's not working. Can anyone help me out of this.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: The UI in my application should not go out of bound w.rt other devices.The Images and text are going out of bound.How to make my UI supportable for multiple screens.

Comment: could you write what attributes are present in the `<compatible-screens>` element of your AndroidManifest?

Comment: and btw this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6476325/multiple-screen-issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It must be done inside layout files, not inside the manifest. Just make your layout flexible enough to run on different screens without going out of bound and becoming unusable.